# Winforms toolbox tools for WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF and I'm wondering is there anyway to have elements from Winforms toolbox in WPF. I mean the Winforms toolbox has a lot of elements and they're not present in WPF toolbox. for example something like PerformanceCounter in Winforms toolbox is not found in WPF toolbox.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some controls that didn't get represented in WPF, but you can use WindowsFormsHost.  As the name indicates, it's purpose is to host the Windows Forms elements.

[Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx)

I would add that things like PerformanceCounter you can use in code, rather than placing it on a form.  Other elements which do have a UI purpose can be placed inside a WindowsFormsHost control.  I do this with ReportViewer -- it's a Windows Forms control that has no WPF equivalent.

Comment: Sure... to the extent that you're setting properties.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx Note that the MaskedTextBox in the example is given an arbitrary namespace of "wf".  Then in the XAML, it's properties are available to be set.  This includes databinding.  Also, the code-behind (or ViewModel if you're using MVVM) can set properties as well... just as you'd expect.